# Display readonly text with MVC Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC Model, with a property defined as:

```
[DisplayName("Service Version")]
public string ServiceVersion { get; set; }
```

On the screen, I want it to display as:

> Service Version: **0.1**

'ServiceVersion' has the version number.

In the view, I have:

```
@model Main_UI.Models.HomeModel
```

And then:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ServiceVersion) @Html.DisplayText(Model.ServiceVersion)
```

This isn't correct, as I get a nothing displayed for the value part. The label appears, but no version number. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Changing the

> @Html.DisplayText(Model.ServiceVersion)

, to just

> @Model.ServiceVersion

has fixed it. Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you try like this `@: Model.ServiceVersion`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

either you can try what @karthik has mentioned in the comments or you can use the attribute

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
[DisplayName("Service Version")]
public string ServiceVersion { get; set; }
```

and in the view use the default

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ServiceVersion) @Html.DisplayText(Model.ServiceVersion)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it just displayed the data ... not the label (From 'DisplayName'. Is there something else I need to do?