# readonly property sends property as null to the controller post action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Inside my viewmodel I have besides other properties Name property which has to be readonly on editing.

On the view side (edit.cshtml) when I add

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
```

I'm  getting property on http post as I should (is not null), but when I use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @readonly = true })
```

I'm getting Name as null on http post action.

In both cases on view form, property is rendered properly.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What browser? and are you really using readonly instead of disabled because the behavior you described is what happens when you use disabled

Comment: readonly double checked. Just find out, I had  [ReadOnly(true)] on that property, when it's removed work perfectly. I thought that readonly passes property just without edit option.

Comment: I think you should use readonly attribute instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715842/display-readonly-text-with-mvc-model